# SKProductRequest return 0 in response

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

Please help me,
I have implement In-App Purchase in my iOS App. And create an In-App purchase on iTunes Connect. This In-App is **"Ready to Submit"** state.
But whenever i am trying with Xcode in iPad **SKProductRequest Response always return 0**.

I have stuck for 2 days but still not found any solution. Please provide me suggestions friends.

One more thing is confusing that in my iTunes Account Contract and Tax information is not fixed. So i think this issue is coming for that?

Because in my Itunes Account Below message is continuously is showing

> You do not currently have a iOS Paid Apps contract in effect. If this In-App Purchase was submitted with your app, then your app will not be available on the App Store until your contract goes into effect. Legal, Admin, and Finance users can go to the Agreements, Tax, and Banking module in iTunes Connect to view your contract status.
>   Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.>

Please suggest where is stuck and why?

Thanks

Comment: looks to me like you need to spend a bit of time in your iTunes-connect account to setup the appropriate contracts, and bank information. For Apple to publish an App with embedded in-app purchases, they need the means to forward you the money, and ensure that proper taxes and stuff are correctly dealt with (depending on your country of origin). So, just go do it ! click click click etc ... for myself setting bank account was the toughest. Rest is easy'ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in-app purchases to work even in sandbox mode, you need to ensure a few things

1. your IAP products are setup correctly
2. you are using the correct mobileprovision files
3. your iOS paid apps contract is agreed to (even if you haven't filled in the information).

Only then you will receive IAP information in your app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have do all above things correctly, but still product.response is return 0. Please suggest another way.

Comment: Do you still see that warning in iTunes Connect? Can you also share code on how you are getting the IAP details?

Comment: Thanks. Finally after set Bank Info and Tax Info with also agreed iOS Paid apps contracts. It is working fine. Thanks. thanks .. Because i passed so much time on it. Thanks for Providing information.